# Check if the first word in string is equal to "print"

Tags: c++

This is the code I'm referring to:

```
string command;
getline(cin, command);
```

For example, when someone enters `"print Hello"`, how can I check if the first word in the string is `"print"`?

Comment: How do you define "word"?  For example, what if someone enters "printhello" or just "print"?  Should either of these match?

Comment: Use a string parser or tokenizer on a space.  Just google "c++ string parser" and there are a ton of examples.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find use find function

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example that utilizes the [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) member function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    std::string command;
    std::getline(std::cin, command);
    if (command.substr(0, command.find(" ")) == "print"){
        std::cout << "Is print.";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Is not print.";
    }
}
```

If all you need to do is check whether the first 5 characters match the "*print*" string literal then use the following conditional that utilizes the [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function:

```
if (command.substr(0, 5) == "print")
```

If you want to check if it is a "*print*" literal followed by a space character use:

```
if (command.substr(0, 6) == "print ")
```

Comment: Could replace `command.find(" ")` with 6 and `"print"` with `"print "`

Comment: @EdHeal Would that not fail for the input `"print"`?

Comment: What actually does the "0" mean in the if?

Comment: @cdhowie - It would - as `"print" != "print "`

Comment: Now, how can I use command.substr to find the last character of the string?

Comment: @MateasMario If you need the last character only then you can use the `back` function.